# How to get Gauss—Legendre nodes and weights in SymPy?

Tags: python-3.x, sympy

SciPy has a set of functions `special.roots_*` that returns the numerical values of roots and weights for corresponding quadratures.

How get the same in SymPy's 'symbolic' form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sympy also has a function that calculates the numerical weights and quadrature points for Gauss-Legendre [as per the documentation](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/integrals/integrals.html?highlight=integrals#numeric-integrals). This function can give results for any desired precision. But if you insist on symbolic results then as long as `n` in a known integer, the following function can do the job:

```
import sympy as sp

sp.init_printing()
x = sp.Symbol('x')

def gauss_legendre(n,x):
    Pnx = sp.legendre(n,x)
    Pp = sp.diff(Pnx,x)
    xi = sp.solve( Pnx, x )
    wi = [ sp.simplify(2/(1 - xj**2)/(Pp.subs(x,xj))**2) for xj in xi ]
    return xi, wi
```

As a test, for `n = 5` this gives

[image]

which matches the [Wikipedia results](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_quadrature#Gauss%E2%80%93Legendre_quadrature).